# Zoom/Pan to annotation on document load - PDFTRON

Tags: annotations, pdftron

I have a requirement, where user creates a point on drawing document(pdf) in pdftron viewer and link to an issue. Later when user clicks on issue i need to set my zoom to the marked location so that it will be helpful for the user to identify where exactly is the issue

I have tried zoomTo method on docViewer class, but unable to get expected result. Can anyone suggest what method we need to use to get the expected result

Comment: And the question? What have you tried so far? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jumpToAnnotation](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/CoreControls.AnnotationManager.html#jumpToAnnotation__anchor) on the AnnotationManager? I believe this is what you are looking for.

> Jumps to the page of the annotation and if it isn't visible then centers it in the window.

Example:

```
// Jumps to passed annotation
annotManager.jumpToAnnotation(annotation);
```